# sp_tables call taking more time which causes blocking

Tags: sql-server, database, perl, dbi

We could see that during our perl program runs which basically connects to SQLserver to insert/delete/update data, the below is called very frequently
`sp_tables @table_name='NOXXTABLE'`. We see that for many SPID's the call happens a lot of times.

On running `sp_tables @table_name='NOXXTABLE'` in SQLserver we can see that it returns no rows. It usually completes in milliseconds.

But after profiling, when we checked the runtime of the particular `SQLText(sp_tables @table_name='NOXXTABLE')` for the blocking SPID's, it was varying from between 0 seconds to 1 minute and was getting called very very frequently within the same SPID. The same is happening for many SPID's which again have multiple calls to `sp_tables` each taking a lot of time.

Is there any solution to get out of this?

Answer (score 4):

The NOXXTABLE is used by DBD::ODBC's ping method. If you call DBI's ping method with DBD::ODBC it does a tables('', '', 'NOXXTABLE', ''). If you want to do it less call ping less or override DBD::ODBC's ping method with other code more appropriate for your system.

Comment: Thanks bohica! 
In that case , from where exactly is ping called and why?
kindly throw some light here. 
We are seeing the sp_tables call in between selects too.
So here how do we call it less number of times ?

Is the tables('', '', 'NOXXTABLE', '') an alternate way of knowing if the DB connection is alive ?
 because there isnt anything called NOXXTABLE and no result is returned.

Comment: I cannot tell you where your code (or the code you are using) is calling ping. What I'm telling you is when the DBI ping method is called and you are using the DBD::ODBC it implements ping by issuing a tables call on the table NOXXTABLE. The argument is that this will require a round trip to the database.